# Ternary operator assignment in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ternary-operator

I found a way to assign a value like this:

```
NSString *result = [self string] ?: @"none";
```

If `[self string]` return a value that not equals to nil, result will be that returning value, else, be @"none". Just like the `or` operator in **Python**.

I tested for several cases, It works fine. Like:

```
int a = 10 ?: 0; // a is 10
int a = 0 ?: 5; // a is 5
NSString *str = @"abc" ?: 10; // warning: incompatible pointer. It has type checking?
```

But I couldn't find any relative documents or information about this syntax. So I wondered why it works. Can somebody explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a GNU extension to C, documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals). Note that it evaluates the expression only once, and reuses the result (useful when your expression has side effects). clang includes it but I can't find any related documentation on that.

---

Edit: Here's the class reference for the implementation with LLVM: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1BinaryConditionalOperator.html

Note that is says:

> BinaryConditionalOperator - The GNU extension to the conditional operator which allows the middle operand to be omitted.

Comment: Totally understand. Thanks a lot.